# Format IntProperty/FloatProperty in GUI layout.prop?

Tags: python, interface, customization, properties

Is there a way to format how the value of Float/Int properties are shown in python blender GUI?

[image]

Right now it's always the same 'text' + 'value' (+ 'unit' if specified in the prop options).

But what if I want to display

```
f"text {value} text"
```

Or even better, format the value with thousands separators?

```
f" text {value:,} text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a formatted text inside the active part of the UI component is not possible, as far as I know.

What you can do, if it suits the UI you would like to get, is to put a label before and after the component with the value, and display only the value.

```
row = layout.row()
row.label(text="prefix")
row.separator(factor=1.0) # Optional. just in case you need more space between components
row.prop(propertyOwner, "property", "text="") #will display the property value without the text inside
row.separator(factor=1.0) # Optional. just in case you need more space between components
row.label(text="suffix")
```

Or, if you don't need the value component to be interactive, you can just draw a simple label, which you will be able to format as any Python string.

```
str = f"Prefix {propertyOwner.property:,} Suffix"
layout.label(text=str)
```